# Assign a [String:AnyObject] to [String:AnyObject] in Swift replaces comma with semi-colon

Tags: ios, swift

I have

```
var params = [String:AnyObject]()
```

I have a function which returns an `[String:AnyObject]`. So, I want to assign that to a key of `params` like this:

```
params["phoneDetails"] = getPhoneDetails()
```

The problem I am facing is, the return of `getPhoneDetails()` is different from the value in `params["phoneDetails"]`.

Here is the output of getPhoneDetails()

```
[locale: en, ostype: 32bit, appversion: 4.0.0, architecture: x86, version: 8.1]
```

Here is the output of `params["phoneDetails"]`:

```
Optional({
    appversion = "4.0.0";
    architecture = "x86 ";
    locale = en;
    ostype = 32bit;
    version = "8.1";
})
```

So, instead of a comma, I see a semi-colon, when using `println(params["phoneDetails"])`.

I want it to be same as the return type of `getPhoneDetails`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The output formatting for println follows its own rules. If you want a different formatting the you need to do that manually.

Comment: My guess would be that getPhoneDetails() returns a tuple not an Dictionary. Where does getPhoneDetails() come from?

Comment: I wrote it. It returns a [String:AnyObject].

Comment: I played around a bit but now I see that my printlns never use `{}` and also no semicolon. Very strange. Can you post a playground excerpt?

Comment: What happens if you run: `println(params["phoneDetails"]!)`? (don't forget the `!` at the end.)

Comment: @Rishi I strongly recommend forgetting you ever saw that `!` until you fully understand what it does...

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity that suggestion was for debugging purposes only (I wasn't sure this Optional could have an impact on the way the inner var was getting printed), but your point in your answer is much more accurate :)

Comment: sorry @Romain, didn’t mean to imply you weren’t aware of the dangers I’m sure you are :) But unfortunately `!`-abuse is so pervasive that whenever I see it mentioned (even legitimately like you say, just a quick test to debug) I wince at the number of people who’s takeaway is “ah, so I just need an exclamation mark there, that’ll fix it”

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this is that Swift is implicitly converting your `Swift.Dictionary` into an `NSDictionary`:

```
let d: [String:AnyObject] = ["one":"1","two":"2"]
// Swift.Dictionary implements Printable.description 
// (which println uses) as [key:value, key:value]
d.description

let nsd = d as NSDictionary
// NSDictionary on the other hand, implements
// it as {\n    key = value;\n   key = value;\n}
nsd.description
```

The reason for this conversion is your use of `AnyObject`.  In theory, `AnyObject` can only store reference types (i.e. classes).  Try the following in a playground *without any import statements at the top* i.e. remove `import UIKit` or whatever:

```
// this won’t even compile - Strings aren’t classes, they’re structs
// so you can’t assign them to AnyObject
let d: [String:AnyObject] = ["one":"1","two":"2"]

// this fixes that:
let e: [String:String] = ["one":"1","two":"2"]
// but this won’t compile:
let o: AnyObject = e  // [String:String] doesn’t conform to protocol AnyObject
```

But `import Foundation` and suddenly magic happens.  Two bits of magic in fact: string literals can now create `NSString` objects, which are classes and so do conform to `AnyObject`.  And Swift dictionaries can be silently converted to `NSDictionary` objects, which also are classes so conform to `AnyObject`.  That latter one is what’s happening to you, and so you get a different output, because your type is indeed of a different type.

If you don’t want them to be of different types, you have two choices – return an `NSDictionary` from your `getPhoneDetails` function (ick) or stop using `AnyObject` and instead declare your dictionary to be of type `[String:[String:String]]` (yay, but leading to stronger types and value rather than reference semantics, which may mean having to refactor other code).

(or I guess you could switch to `[String:Any]` but there lies madness)